# Using gzip as a reducer produces corrupt data

Tags: hadoop, compression, hadoop-streaming

When I run hadoop streaming like this:

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar 
       -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=16
       -input foo
       -output bar
       -mapper "python zot.py"
       -reducer gzip
```

I get 16 files in the output directory which are, alas, corrupt:

```
$ hadoop fs -get bar/part-00012
$ file part-00012
gzip compressed data, from Unix
$ cat part-00012 | gunzip >/dev/null

gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
```

when I inspect the output of `cat part-00012 | gunzip` visually, I see parts which look somewhat right and then quite wrong and then `gunzip` dies.

- why is the file corrupt?

PS. I know I can have my data set split into a small number gzip-compressed files using  [`mapred.output.compress=true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767799/hadoop-streaming-produces-uncompressed-files-despite-mapred-output-compress-true).

PPS. This is for [vw](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/vowpal_wabbit/conversations/messages/3671).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use output.compress directly in the jobconf settings. No need to send it through gzip. 
See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767799/hadoop-streaming-produces-uncompressed-files-despite-mapred-output-compress-true]) to your other question.

Comment: Thanks. However, why are my files corrupt here?

Comment: In theory it should have worked. It's just input via stdin, which gzip handles fine. The pattern you're using is a bit unorthodox in the Hadoop world. All I can think of is that it's not closing the gzip archieve properly on reducer termination.

Comment: if your theory were right (about closing) then most of the file would have been okay. this is not the case.